# JS Can't update a value in HTML connected to a value in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to update the value inside an array of objects using this

syntax: array[objectindex].key = array[objectindex].key + 1;

on console.log work perfectly taking the value from the object, the problem is the value in the object isn't updated.

I'm trying to update SCORE BOARDS with a function inside MATCHING.

I use that value as a scoring point in HTML.

```js
//-----------------CARDS DECK--------------------
var cards = [
    {
    rank:"Queen",
    suit: "Hearts",
    cardImage: "images/queen-of-hearts.png"
    },
    {
    rank: "Queen",
    suit: "Dimonds",
    cardImage: "images/queen-of-diamonds.png"
    },
    {rank: "King",
    suit: "Hearts",
    cardImage: "images/king-of-hearts.png"
    },
    {
    rank: "King",
    suit: "Diamonds",
    cardImage: "images/king-of-diamonds.png"
    }
];

//-----------------SCORE BOARDS-----------------
var score = [
    {
    points:0,
    parent: 'left-board',
    side:"p1"
    },
    {
    points:0,
    parent:'right-board',
    side:"ai"
    }
];

var cardsInPlay = [];

//----------------CREATE THE GAMEBOARD-----------
var createBoard = function () {
    for (var i=0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
        cardElement.setAttribute('src','images/back.png');
        cardElement.setAttribute('data-id',i);
        cardElement.addEventListener('click',flipCard);
        document.getElementById('game-board').appendChild(cardElement);
        
    } 
}

//--------------CREATE SCORE-------------------
var createScore = function () {
    for (var i=0; i < score.length; i++) {
        var scoreElement = document.createElement('div');
        scoreElement.setAttribute('class','points');
        scoreElement.setAttribute('id',score[i].side);
        document.getElementById(score[i].parent).appendChild(scoreElement);
        document.getElementById(score[i].side).innerHTML=score[i].points;
    }
}


//----------------FLIPCARD----------------------
var flipCard = function () {
    var cardId = this.getAttribute("data-id");
    console.log("User flipped over " + cards[cardId].rank);
    console.log(cards[cardId].suit);
    console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
    cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
    this.setAttribute('src',cards[cardId].cardImage);
    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
        setTimeout(checkForMatch,300);
        //reset();
    }   
}
//----------------MATCHING------------------------
function checkForMatch() {
    if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
        alert("You found a match!");
        score[0].points ++;
        console.log(score[0]);
    
        
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry, try again.");
    }
    
}

//----------------GAME RESET---------------------

var reset = function () {
    for (var i=0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i].setAttribute('src','images/back.png');
    }
    cardsInPlay = [];
    
}


//##############---INVOKING----#####################
createScore();
createBoard();


//score[0].points =
console.log(score[0].points);
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Raleway;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 45px;
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    font-family: Raleway;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

a:hover {
   border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  }

h2 {
    font-family: Raleway;
    color: #0d2c40;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20;
}

p {
    font-family: "Droid Serif";
    line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 18px; 
}

header {
    background-color: #F15B31;
    padding: 30px 20px;
}

main {
    width: auto;
    margin: 35px auto;
}

nav {
    background: #00A6B3;
    padding:20px 0;
}

.navlink {
    margin:0 20px;
    color: white;
} 

img {
    margin: 20px 8px;
}

footer {
    background-color:#0D2C40;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.copyright {
    font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
    float: left;
}

.message{
    font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
    float: right;
}

.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .name {
      color:#F15B31;
      font-weight: 700;
  }

  .point-board {
      border-style: solid;
      position: absolute;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      border-radius: 90px;
      line-height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Raleway;
  }

  #left-board {
    top: 630px;
    left: 70px;
  }

  #right-board {
    top: 630px;
    left: 1152px;
  }

  .points {
      margin: -50px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif|Raleway:400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Marco's memory game</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Marco's memory game</h1>
    </header>
        <nav>
            <a class="navlink" href="#instructions">Instructions</a>
            <a class="navlink" href="#facts">Game facts</a>
            <a class="navlink" href="#game-board">Play!</a>

        </nav>

    

    
    <main>
        <h2 id="instructions">Instructions</h2>
        <p>Concentration, also known as Match Match, Memory, Pelmanism, Shinkei-suijaku, Pexeso or simply Pairs, is a card game
            in which all of the cards are laid face down on a surface and two cards are flipped face up over each turn. The
            object of the game is to turn over pairs of matching cards.</p>

        <h2 id="facts">Game's facts</h2>
        <p>An other popular memory game is called "Kim's game. Kim's Game is a game or exercise played by Boy Scouts, Girl Scouts
            and Girl Guides, and other children's groups.[1] The game develops a person's capacity to observe and remember
            details. The name is derived from Rudyard Kipling's 1901 novel Kim, in which the hero, Kim, plays the game during
            his training as a spy.
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim%27s_Game">More info...</a>
        </p>
       
        <div class="point-board" id="left-board">PLAYER
            <div class="points" id= "p1"></div>


        </div>

        <h2>Play!</h2>
        <div id="game-board" class="board clearfix"></div>
        
        <div class="point-board" id="right-board">AI
                <div class="points" id= "ai">00</div>
        </div>
        
    </main>
    
    
    

    <footer class="clearfix">

        <p class="copyright">Copyright 2017</p>
        <p class="message">Created with &hearts; by <span class="name"> GA </span></p>
        
       
    </footer>


    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: score[0].points ++;
        console.log(score[0]);

adding this string it shows like it updated, but it doesn't update the HTML.
I'm adding the rest of the code (CSS + HTML)

Comment: You need to put the new score into the html after you increment it.

Comment: @refeniz like this?

function checkForMatch() {
    if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
        alert("You found a match!");
        document.getElementById(score[0].side).innerHTML=score[0].points ++;
        console.log(score[0]);
    
        
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry, try again.");
    }
    
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code isn't working, but you can use `++` to simplify that statement...

```
score[0].points++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```html
function checkForMatch() {
    if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
        alert("You found a match!");
        document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=score[0].points + 1;
        console.log(score[0]);
    
        
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry, try again.");
    }
    
}
```